# A clear definition for procedural security controls?

Tags: corporate-policy, defense

1. Can you please provide a clear definition for **procedural security controls**?
2. Are operational and procedural security controls synonyms?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a google search? Wiki has a nice overview ... Aside from that, I am not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes. Google will tell you that controls are technical, management and operational.

Comment: @schroeder Yes, I have tried googling prior to asking the question. Wiki has a few examples, not a definition. I'm asking for clear definition.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: I know what technical, management and operational controls are. The question is about procedural security controls.

Comment: I'm not sure that you will find anything more than that. It's a category - a distinction. Security controls that take the form of procedures, policies, and processes. As opposed to physical and technical controls.

Comment: I don't know how to make a request for definition narrower. There is no definition for what I asked easily found on internet (I couldn't find). That's why it was asked in the first place. I'm sorry it didn't fit your rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedural security controls are security controls that mitigate identified risks by way of policies, procedures or guidelines. As opposed to other controls, procedural controls rely on users to follow rules or performs certain steps that are not necessarily enforced by technical or physical means.

How about that for a definition? By no means official as there is no official definition as far as I know.

Procedural controls and operational controls are not synonyms in my opinion. Technical or physical controls can be operational as well. Organizational controls comes to mind as most similar.